# php simplexml with spreadshirt api

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml

I'm trying to use Spreadshirt API to create a product on their platform, but i'm stuck with this weird error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/anarchoi/public_html/test.php:102 Stack trace: #0 /home/anarchoi/public_html/test.php(102): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in /home/anarchoi/public_html/test.php on line 102
```

Most of the code is just copied from their wiki so i really don't understand why it doesn't work.

I'm looking for help to understand where the error is coming from and why it is happening.

```
$productTypeId = "210";
$printTypeId = "17";
$printColorIds = "13,20";
$productTypeAppearanceId = "1";
$productTypePrintAreaId = "4";
$designId = "10438193";

// 1. Get shop data
$shopUrl = "http://api.spreadshirt.com/api/v1/shops/266497";
$ch = curl_init($shopUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close the handle
curl_close($ch);

$shop = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
$namespaces = $shop->getNamespaces(true);

// 2. Get product type data
$attributes = $shop->productTypes->attributes($namespaces['xlink']);
$productTypeUrl = $attributes->href . "/" . $productTypeId;
$ch = curl_init($productTypeUrl);
// echo "<br>$productTypeUrl<br>";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close the handle
curl_close($ch);

$productType = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

// 3. Get design data
$attributes = $shop->designs->attributes($namespaces['xlink']);
$designUrl = $attributes->href . "/" . $designId;
$ch = curl_init($designUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close the handle
curl_close($ch);

$design = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

// 4. Prepare product
// get positioning data for selected product type
$printArea = null;
foreach ($productType->printAreas->printArea as $current) {
    if ($current['id'] == $productTypePrintAreaId) {
        $printArea = $current;
    }
}

$product = new SimpleXMLElement(getFileData("product.xml"));
$product->productType['id'] = $productTypeId;
$product->appearance['id'] = $productTypeAppearanceId;
$configuration = $product->configurations->configuration;
$configuration->printArea['id'] = $productTypePrintAreaId;
$configuration->printType['id'] = $printTypeId;
$configuration->offset->x =
          ((doubleval($printArea->boundary->size->width) - doubleval($design->size->width)) / 2);
$configuration->offset->y =
          ((doubleval($printArea->boundary->size->height) - doubleval($design->size->height)) / 4);
$image = $product->configurations->configuration->content->svg->image;
$image['width'] = $design->size->width;
$image['height'] = $design->size->height;
$image['designId'] = $designId;
$image['printColorIds'] = $printColorIds;

// 5. Create product
$attributes = $shop->products->attributes($namespaces['xlink']);
$productsUrl = $attributes->href;

$header = array();
$header[] = createSprdAuthHeader("POST", $productsUrl);
$header[] = "Content-Type: application/xml";

$ch = curl_init("$productsUrl"."?fullData=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $product->asXML());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close the handle
curl_close($ch);
$productUrl = parseHttpHeaders($result, "Location");

$ch = curl_init($productUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close the handle
curl_close($ch);

$product = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
$resource = $product->resources->resource[0];
$attributes = $resource->attributes($namespaces['xlink']);

echo '<html><body>';
echo 'Product available at: <a href="' . $productUrl . '">' . $productUrl . '</a></br>';
echo 'Product image is available at: <a href="' . $attributes->href . '">' . $attributes->href . '</a></br>';
echo '<img src="' . $attributes->href . '?width=1000"/>';
echo '</body></html>';

function createSprdAuthHeader($method, $url) {
    $apiKey = "***";
    $secret = "***";
    $time = time()*1000;

    $data = "$method $url $time";
    $sig = sha1("$data $secret");

    return "Authorization: SprdAuth apiKey=\"$apiKey\", data=\"$data\", sig=\"$sig\"";
}

function parseHttpHeaders( $header, $headername ) {
    $retVal = array();
    $fields = explode("\r\n", preg_replace('/\x0D\x0A[\x09\x20]+/', ' ', $header));
    foreach( $fields as $field ) {
        if( preg_match('/('.$headername.'): (.+)/m', $field, $match) ) {
            return $match[2];
        }
    }
    return $retVal;
}

function getFileData($file) {
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    $data = "";
    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $data .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return $data;
}
```

product.xml = https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/product.xml

Comment: Which is line 102? Output the data you pass to SimpleXMLElement(), it's likely not what you are expecting.

Comment: 102 = $product = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

Comment: Before that line, do `var_dump($result);exit();` and see what it shows.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon similar issue when implementing Spreadshirt, looks like their API server is sending (at least some) content gzipped regardless of any `Accept-Encoding` headers. You can tell that it's your case by `var_dump`ing the string before it's passed to `SimpleXMLElement` (as suggested by others) – if it's gibberish, it's very possible you have the same issue as I did.

Setting the curl option of `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to an empty string (`''`) fixed that for me – it "magically" turned on ungzipping the response (see [man page for `curl_setopt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more information).